# How to pass git-tag to Gitlab .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm about to tag a git commit with a release number and I was wondering if I could use that in the yaml file within the script.

Like this:

```
Git tag: MyTag "1.2.3.4"  <---this is the tag info
```

and then in the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
script:
  - MyPowerShellScript.ps1 MyTag
```

My hope is that it will execute: `MyPowerShellScript.ps1 1.2.3.4`

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the tag name from .yaml by using

```
$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

I hope I got the question right.